# Runing a script file taking a file from other directory as an argument

Tags: bash

So I tried to do something like above,but is says no such file or directory.Is there any possible way to still run it like that but wont get that error.Perhaps something to do with the argument declared in my script file itself.Currently my script file code has $1 as the argument.Hope someone can help.Thank you

Comment: Are you sure you're passing your script the absolute path of the file you're trying to use as argument ?

Comment: so my scriptfile is inside directory workspaceA .I have a subdirectory in that workspaceA and it contains many files.I want to run it like  ./myscript.sh filename,but from workspaceA.So what should i change..  My script file code :  cat $1 | grep -c "mypattern" $1   @user1858268

Comment: If it's inside a directory where your script is located, then  `./myscript.sh subdirectory/filename` should work.

Comment: Make sure you are *double-quoting* `"$1"` in your script to protect against *word-splitting* if there is whitespace in your path/filename argument and protect against *path expansion*. And look at the `basename` and `dirname` builtins.

Comment: Can you post the relevant section of the script? That would help in determining the problem.